# Get text of TextView inside RecyclerView - android instrumental test

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I have a RecyclerView with items from item.xml.
In item.xml i have a TextView.

I'm working on creating an instrumental test and wondering how could I get the text from that textview from the recyclerView so that I can do some extra work with it.

Using https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/04/15/espresso-testing-recyclerviews/ I managed to check if the text that I would expect is where I would expect it to be, but I need to get the value as well.

Error code:

```
descendant: with string from resource id: <2131427419>' doesn't match the selected view when calling onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.recycler_view).atPosition(2)) .check(matches(hasDescendant(withText(R.id.my_textview))));
```

Comment: did you notice: `onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.scroll_view).atPosition(3))
    .check(matches(hasDescendant(withText("Some content"))));` ? For getting value of `TextView` use `ViewMatchers.withText()` method

Comment: Still, withText(resourceId) will return a ViewInteraction, don't understand how I can get the String from this. (new to testing)

As well, i get an error `descendant: with string from resource id: <2131427419>' doesn't match the selected view` when calling `onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.recycler_view).atPosition(2))
                .check(matches(hasDescendant(withText(R.id.my_textview))));`

Comment: please edit your post and add this code as EDIT

Comment: I need this as well. 4 years later still no answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String title = ((TextView) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position).itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_textview)).getText().toString();
```